# Floyd-Warshall algorithm implementation not working

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am working on implementing the Floyd-Warshall algorithm for an assignment and the output matrix is incorrect. I've double checked my algorithm against others online and it looks the same as others. Am I just missing something? Any help is appreciated.

My **input file** is :

```
4

 0  2  2 -1

-1  0  2  3

-1 -1  0  2

-1 -1 -1  0
```

The **Resultant Matrix** Should be :

```
 0  2  2  4

-1  0  2  3

-1 -1  0  2

-1 -1 -1  0
```

The **Path Matrix** should be :

```
0 0 0 3

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0
```

I'm receiving as my **Resultant Matrix :**

```
-4 -3 -2 -5

-5 -4 -3 -6

-6 -5 -4 -7

-7 -6 -5 -8
```

And for the **Path Matrix :**

```
4 4 4 4

4 4 4 4

4 4 4 4

4 4 4 4
```

Here is the **code** for my program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Forward Declarations
void readFile();
void fillPathWithZeros();
void findFloydsAlgorithmMatrix();
void printGraph(vector< vector<int> >& inVector, string heading);

int size;
vector< vector<int> > M; // Matrix with weights
vector< vector<int> > P; // Path Matrix

int main()
{
    readFile();
    fillPathWithZeros();
    findFloydsAlgorithmMatrix();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void readFile()
{
    int z = 0;

    ifstream file("example.txt", fstream::in); // File name  is example.txt
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        // read characters by using "file >>" 
        file >> z;
        size = z;
        vector< vector<int> > fileGraph(size, vector<int>(size)); // creates a local 2D vector to size stated in file
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                file >> fileGraph[i][j];
            }
        } 

        M = fileGraph; // Copies the local vector to a global vector to be used in other functions
        printGraph(fileGraph, "Input matrix M: "); // Print out the input Matrix
    }


}

// Initialize the Path Vector with all 0's
void fillPathWithZeros()
{
    vector< vector<int> > localPathGraph(size, vector<int>(size));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            localPathGraph[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    P = localPathGraph; // set the local Path Vector to the Global Path Vector
}

void findFloydsAlgorithmMatrix()
{

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                    if ( ( M[i][k] + M[k][j] ) < M[i][j] ) {
                        M[i][j] = M[i][k] + M[k][j];
                        P[i][j] = k + 1;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    printGraph(M, "Resultant matrix M: ");
    printGraph(P, "Path matrix P: ");

}

void printGraph(vector< vector<int> >& inVector, string heading){

    cout << heading << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            cout << setw(2) << inVector[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: 1) After the call to readFile(), did you make sure that the input was received OK?  2) The loop to initialize the matrix to 0 need not be written.  Just use the constructor of vector: `vector< vector<int> > localPathGraph(size, vector<int>(size,0));`

Comment: For #1 The input is being received OK. I print it out as soon as I'm done adding it to the vector in readFile(). So that's fine. For #2 I did not know that thank you for telling me.

Comment: 1) Are you sure there are no negative cycles in your Matrix?  Floyd-Warshall doesn't work with negative cycles.  See here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

For a test, try a 3 x3 or even a 2 x 2 matrix and only use positive numbers.  Looking at your code, it seems ok (some things can be cleaned up, but that's another story).

Comment: That's exactly what it was. The -1's from the input file was causing the problem. Thank you very much for your help, PaulMcKenzie.

Comment: Yes, the standard representation for Floyd algorithm sets infinite instead of your -1. MAX INT would be enough in your case.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Put your comment as an answer,  Mopikope will surely check it and other people could vote it up. Only they are no negative cycles, but negative distances, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are negative distances in your matrix.  Floyd-Warshall doesn't work with negative distances or cycles.

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

As far as your code goes, it looks ok from an algorithmic standpoint.  Some things can be done in a shorter amount of code (such as the initialization of the vectors), but other than that, the code should work if the matrix doesn't have negative distances/cycles.